# scrolling programmatically to item in ListView when using CustomListViewAdapter

Tags: android, listview, listview-adapter

I am trying to scroll programmatically to a certain position within a list view while using a CustomListViewAdapter.

I use a customlistviewadapter because whenever an item within the listview is clicked, it "opens up" to display some text. It is at that point that I want to scroll programmatically to the top of the text just displayed.

At present, it all works fine, EXCEPT that I don't know how to call the function:

```
listview.setSelection(currentPosition);
```

I cannot seem to get to it within the CustomListViewAdapter which is where I listen for the click event on the listview item.

I have tried calling:

```
parent.setSelected(true);
```

Just after the item is clicked and the function

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

is called, but it does nothing.

How can I call

```
listview.setSelection(currentPosition);
```

or even better:

```
listview.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position,offset,duration);
```

Within the CustomListViewAdapter class?

Below is the code of CustomListViewAdapter.

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

Context context;
ArrayList<RowItem> _rowItems;
RowItem item;
View row;
TextView ReferenceGospel;

  public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                             ArrayList<RowItem> rowItems) {


    super(context, resourceId, rowItems);
    this.context = context;
    _rowItems = rowItems;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
row = convertView;
item = _rowItems.get(position);

 if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.book_list, parent, false);
        row.setTag(thisPosition);

    }

ReferenceGospel = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.gospelRef);

// ... some other code here

ReferenceGospel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            item = _rowItems.get(position);
            CustomListViewAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
     });
    return row;
}
```

I have looked at several posts but none help.
Thank you.

Comment: "it "opens up" to display some text." can you explain more ? like text is displayed on seperate dialogue on listview item itself ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. By opening it up i mean a list item becomes visible ... i have not included the code that does that. So it is a listview item itself.

Comment: @Sahil, the app is available to download where you can see clearly what I mean by displaying some text. If it helps I can send you the link to the app. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the listview in constructor of adapter:

```
ListView listView;

  public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, ListView listView,
                         ArrayList<RowItem> rowItems) {


 super(context, resourceId, rowItems);
 this.context = context;
 this.listView = listView;
 _rowItems = rowItems;

}
```

then you can call `listview.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position,offset,duration);`
from getView method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you. It helps. Of course, all I had to do was pass the listview to adapter. Brilliant, thanks for your help, it works perfectly!